# Providing downlaod link to file in non-public section of server

Tags: php, html, download, directory, private

I have a number of files stored in a folder outside of the publicly accessible portion of my website.

For example, the file `'abcd.jpg'` is stored (in terms of the server) in `'/home/private_files/'` and the website is in `'/home/public_html/website.com/'`

When I go to provide a link to view the file, I use

`<a href="/home/private_files/abcd.jpg">Download</a>` however this doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache as the server, you can set it to alias a directory in httpd.conf...

```
Alias /images/ "/home/private_files/"

<Directory "/home/private_files/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

</IfModule>
```

and you can use this

```
<a href="/images/abcd.jpg">Download</a>
```

Comment: I will give this a try, thanks! But if I were to go to `www.mysite.com/images/abcd.jpg` would I be able to see the file? Because the whole reason why I put them in a non-public folder was to prevent this?

Comment: you can replace this  Allow from [Your ip ADDRESS] to the directory structure last line to allow acess to your ip address only , hopwe this works for you

Answer (score 0):

You can not access to directory that located in out of www.

use [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to link to file:

```
ln -s /home/private_files/abcd.jpg /home/www/abcd.jpg
```

and delete the link after deadline(something like rapidshare)

or use file downloader like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531292/how-to-force-download-of-a-file)

Comment: I will also give this a shot, but can you suggest how I might do this in PHP?

Comment: I think you forgot to see the class that I linked to. You shoud read file with this **bold** `readfile('/home/private_files/abcd.jpg');` and use the header to show download window to client like **bold** `header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename=\"new_file_name\""); `