# download link not working in phone gap browser, hybrid mobile app with HTML5, CSS, Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am developing a Hybrid Mobile app using HTML5, CSS and Javascript. I create apk using PhoneGap. I installed the app in a phone. The Problem is that when I click download, the file is opened and not downloaded.

My code is

```
<a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Download filename" href="mywebsiteURL/Upload/filename.extension" >
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Download filename" href="mywebsiteURL/Upload/filename.extension" target="_blank">
```

However, if the file extension is known for browser (such as images) it opens within the browser and you need to send header ([via php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531292/how-to-force-download-of-a-file) for example) in order to force it to download. More info on [server-side scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting)

Comment: How do I send header?? I don't know php. Is there any way I can do it without php? Thanks a lot for your help. @Amin

Comment: @VincentPaukgyi You can do it with any language but you need to setup a server. I add a more info link at the end of the answer.