# PHP displays the content of file instead of downloading it

Tags: php, download, readfile, display

I am currently working on a CMS and I want the users to download .xls and .csv files through php. I tried literally everything I found to implement it, but everytime it was displayed in the html instead of downloading, and it happens when I try to download a simple .txt file too, so basically for every file download. I tried the `readfile()` method and PHPExcel's `save('php://output');` command but none of them downloaded the file. I wonder if I should look for the bug not in my code but somewhere else (.htaccess, apache settings maybe?). Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Issue proper headers for the content type before printing the output

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30116201/4007002

Comment: Add proper content types.