# Corrupted image on auto download using url with curl in php

Tags: php, url, curl, download

I want to download images from my server without clicking anything - when my php file executes it will download automatically, but the problem is the file is corrupt.  However, when I paste the url directly in the browser and download, it works perfectly.  So why does my implementation below not work? Any ideas about this?

Here's my code:

```
$url_to_image = 'https://hideserver.com/axul-display/assets/ads/';
$ch = curl_init($url_to_image);
$my_save_dir = 'assets/ads/';
$filename = basename($url_to_image.'ads-id-4.gif');
$complete_save_loc = $my_save_dir . $filename;
$fp = fopen($complete_save_loc, 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, FALSE);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: i have tried to connect from Norway, Sweden, and France, the server at `hideserver.com` (52.73.179.54) refuses TCP connections on port 443 (the default httpS port). can anyone else communicate with that server?

Comment: @hanshenrik sorry I hide the server cause its private server, can I pm to you the server? thank you

Comment: well, enable CURLOPT_VERBOSE and post the verbose log. run  ```$out=fopen("php://output","wb");curl_setopt_array($ch,array(CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>1,CURLOPT_STDERR=>$out));``` before running curl_exec, what do you get?

Comment: * Hostname server***.com was found in DNS cache * Trying 128.199.***.***... * Connected to server***.com (128.199.***.***) port 80 (#0) > GET /axul-display/assets/ads/ HTTP/1.1 Host: server***.com Accept: */* < HTTP/1.1 200 OK < Date: Wed, 21 Nov 2018 22:49:17 GMT < Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) < Vary: Accept-Encoding < Content-Length: 2854 < Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8 <

Comment: @hanshenrik can I have your email so that I can email to you the server, thank you

Comment: sure, my email is available at https://stackoverflow.com/users/1067003/hanshenrik?tab=profile

Comment: @henshenrik I sent you invitation on hang out pls see thank you.

Comment: @henshenrik pls see your email I already sent the server name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi everyone thanks to your help, but I solved my own problem instead of curl I used this very simple code.

$image_url = 'http://server***.com/axul-display/assets/ads/ads-id-4.gif';

```
file_put_contents('assets/ads/ads-id-4.gif', file_get_contents($image_url));
```

Big thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

With reference to answer posted on [php - How to force download of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531292/php-how-to-force-download-of-a-file)

Instead of curl call use headers to download file.

```
$file_name = 'ads-id-4.gif';
$file_url = 'https://hideserver.com/axul-display/assets/ads/' . 
$file_name;
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\"");
readfile($file_url);
exit;
```

Comment: OP is not trying to make php output the image to stdout, OP is trying to make the php script save the image to the system that php is running on.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me..

```
 $ch = curl_init($url);
    if (in_array($type, ['jpg', 'jpeg','png'])) {
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYSTATUS, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, fopen($temp_path, 'wb'));
    curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
```