# Based on url parameters, file should get renamed before file is downloaded

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have some files in a server, there are many articles pointing to the files, sometimes the url are misspelled. I want to serve the file no matter what the url was. For that I want the file on the server to be renamed before getting downloaded by a user without actually renaming the original file. Since there would be many requests to the original file.
For example. If the file is `Book of Reliable.pdf` , and the url the user clicks is `http://example.com/Book of Reliance.pdf` , I want the user to download the file as `Book of Reliable.pdf`

I think we can achieve this by renaming the actual file. But I want the original file to be untouched.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php - How to force download of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531292/php-how-to-force-download-of-a-file)

Answer (score 1):

Simulate a rename using HTTP headers, like:

```
$name = 'my-file-name.txt';
header('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename="' . $name . '"');
```

> **Note** to replace `inline` with `attachment` if you want the Browser to show "Save As..." dialog.

Comment: duplicate, sir? https://stackoverflow.com/a/531418/5882307

Comment: No, it's a little different Q/A above; However, such little facts are not even copyright-able, as they are required in many situations as is.

Comment: yeah.... 